# How to add field to ALL webforms?

Tags: forms, webforms

How do I add a field to all webforms?
I have a website where I'm using webform for surveys and I want that on each survey there will be a field that is the same in all of the nodes/webforms.
Thank you.

Comment: did you mean to show the webform everywhere in nodes and webform pages?  in that case there is an option in webfrom settings that you can have your webform available as a block. and after doing that you can configure your webform block every where you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Go to `/admin/structure/types/manage/webform/fields` and add a field. Then all your new webforms will use the new field.
- Install the [Webform Share](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_share) module, create a webform as usual, create your field, click the `Export` tab, go to `/admin/structure/types/manage/webform` and paste your configuration in the `Publishing options > Webform default components` box.

If all you need is one simple field, I recommend the former option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to /admin/structure/types and find your webform content type.
2. Go to manage fields of your webform content type
3. Add your new field like any other content type[image: webform content type]
4. After setting your desired field, go to manage display of your content type and decide the order of your fields
5. In my case I have a full node[image: display customization]